# Facebook Share URL Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

I'm trying to add facebook sharing button to my wordpress theme. I'm always receving "Sorry, something went wrong. We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can."

This is my code:

```
    // Get current page URL 
    $URL = urlencode(get_permalink());
    $facebookURL = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='.$URL;
    $content .= '<a class="social-link social-facebook" href="'.$facebookURL.'" target="_blank">Share</a>';
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you developing locally? If so Facebook cannot reach your local URL and that maybe why you are getting that error.

For additional debugging try replacing `$URL` with a public url e.g.

```
$URL = 'google.com';// urlencode(get_permalink());
```

If you get the same message I would think this is an issue with Facebook.